# Connect Sum of a connected, compact manifold of dimension n and $S^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

$M $ be a connected,compact manifold of dimension n.
Show that $ M \# S^n$ is homeomorphic to $M$

My idea: $S^n-D^n$ is homeomorphic to $D^n$..so $M \# S^n$ is homeomorphic to $(M-D^n) \cup D^n$ ...which is homeomorphic to $M$...
Is this right?

Comment: Yes, your intuition is correct. You just need to formalize it.